# pv permission denied, but dd works without error

Tags: dd, cloning

`pv` is program running above `dd`. I am cloning my old HDD to a new SSD. It's 500GB of data. I tried to run the following command to copy `sda` to `sdb`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sudo pv < /dev/sda > /dev/sdb
bash: /dev/sda: Permission denied
```

Using `dd` command did not produce this error.

I am running the system Ubuntu from the DVD. `sda` is the main laptop harddrive connected over SATA, `sdb` is SSD drive connected over USB using USB-SATA converter.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do you monitor the progress of dd?](/q/215505)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The redirections above are setup by your shell before forking and execing sudo. You may want something like the following:

```
sudo bash -c 'pv < /dev/sda > /dev/sdb'
```

This will cause `bash` to be run by `sudo`. Bash will execute the parameter to the `-c` arg as a command in that shell rather than running interactively.

The `dd` command worked because presumably you didn't use redirections with it.

Also, `pv` doesn't run above `dd`. The `pv` command does lots of things, including showing progress of its output to stdout  or rate limiting its output.

Comment: Thank you. And can you reassure me that the `pv </dev/sda  >/dev/sdb` copies from `sda` to `sdb`? It would be nasty if I got all my sourcecode and personal data accidentally deleted.

Comment: I would look into `rsync` for that use case.